# Broad, Large, Wide View

Tags: word-choice, adjectives

Could it be that a broad view, a large view and a wide view the same, as in these sentences:

> 1. He took a ***broad*** view of the situation.
> 2. He took a ***large*** view of the situation.
> 3. He took a ***wide*** view of the situation.

Are they different?

Comment: Okay, so as I said there ... *large* and *wide* are the words generally used for a scenery whereas if the matter is about mental attribute, I have seen *broad* in sentences. So, here, the appropriate sentence is the first one. Second and third, I won't vote for :)

Comment: [Not a glitch, it seems.](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/30681/broad-large-and-wide-view/30684#30684)

Answer (score 2):

Broad and wide are synonyms and can usually be used interchangeably. They are both adjectives for a horizontal dimension.

In your example it is most likely being used metaphorically, it conveys the idea of a military commander surveying a battlefield and taking into account everything that is happening at the periphery, to left and right, as well as at the centre.

Taking a broad view is certainly idiomatic, perhaps clichéd.

Large is different, it can be applied to a variety of dimensions and quantities. It doesn't have the same connotations.